# Returning result_array() as numeric array, NOT as associative array

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I do iteration with for loop and I can't use result of result_array() as associative array, I need to refer to elements by numbers . Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: outstanding, best answer soon